# str-replace Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, str-replace

I have this code as anti-html and sql injection for a online game but it doesn't work and gives me the following error:

```
    Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference
```

Here is my code:

```
    $_POST = str_replace('<', '>', '\'', '\'', '\\', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&#39; ', '&#92;', $_POST);
    $_GET = str_replace('<', '>', '\'', '\'', '\\', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&#39;', '&#92;', $_GET);
```

It's for the first of the two lines, but i'm sure that the problem will be for the second one too. I'm not good at php and these are files i took from the web.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to implement your own XSS filter, as there is already existing [one](http://php.net/htmlentities)

And you can take advantage of this in this way:

```
$_POST = filter($_POST);
$_GET = filter($_GET);

function filter(array $value) {
        return is_array($value) ? array_map(__FUNCTION__, $value) : htmlentities($value);

}
```

This will filter nested arrays as well (in case your input was like `name[]`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this :

```
$post_vars = array();

for ($i=0; i<count($_POST); $i++)
{
    $post_vars[$i] = str_replace('<', '>', '\'', '\'', '\\', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&#39; ', '&#92;', $_POST[$i]);
}
```

Same goes for the $_GET array.

Comment: Yes, and this is not good solution to protect from XSS. This can be easily hacked by naming an input as array, like `<input type="name" name="foo[]" />`. And also this is not a full alphabet